# CLNDR.js somehow not passing full days.events data to template? ONLY in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, underscore.js

I could really use some help here. About have this calendar business wrapped up but just went to test everything in IE and the underscore JS template is not getting the first "row" of event data for the calendar.

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y072a94e/3/

If you run that fiddle on Chrome it correctly (though the size is a bit ugly) displays the event on March 2nd, 4th, and 5th. (Weekly totals also has something to work with and adds them up in the first row).

On IE , however, this does not work, but strangely enough, the events from march 10th and on DO show up.

I poked around in debugger for IE and noticed that with a break point at this spot in my underscore.js template:

```
 {% _.each(days, function(day) { %}
                {% debugger; %}
                <div class="{{ day.classes }}">{{ day.day }}
```

The days array at index 1  (march 2nd) doesn't actually have an "events" object for that day. It's just not there at all. So somehow CLNDR.js is taking the first few elements out of the events array before passing it to underscore? I'm not sure how to figure this out. =X

Note: I'm using IE10 and Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m

Template:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //switch out delimiters for underscore
        _.templateSettings = {
            interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,      // print value: {{ value_name }}
            evaluate: /\{%([\s\S]+?)%\}/g,   // excute code: {% code_to_execute %}
            escape: /\{%-([\s\S]+?)%\}/g
        }; // excape HTML: {%- <script> %} prints &lt;script&gt;
    </script>

<div id="full-clndr"></div>   

    <script id="clndrTemplate" type="text/template">
        {% 
            var weeklyTotals = 0;
            var weekTicker = 0; 
            var weeklyTotalsArray = [];
        %}
        <div class="clndr-controls">
          <div class="clndr-previous-button arrow"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 5px;"><</span></div>          
          <div class="clndr-next-button arrow"><span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: large; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 5px;">></span></div>
          <div class="month">{{ month }}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clndr-grid">
          <div class="days-of-the-week">
            {% _.each(daysOfTheWeek, function(day) { %}
              <div class="header-day">{{ day }}</div>
            {% }); %}
            <div class="days">

              {% _.each(days, function(day) { %}

                <div class="{{ day.classes }}">{{ day.day }}

                <br />                   
                <div class="deposit">
                    {%if(day.events.length > 0){ %}                      
                        <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">${{day.events[0].title}}</a>

                    {% if (weekTicker < 7){
                        weeklyTotals = weeklyTotals + Number(day.events[0].title);                         
                    } %}

                    {%}%}
                </div>
                                    {%
                weekTicker += 1;

                if(weekTicker == 7){                              
                    weeklyTotalsArray.push(weeklyTotals);    
                    weekTicker = 0; 
                    weeklyTotals = 0;
                }

                %}
                </div>
              {% }); %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="event-listing">
            <p id="weeklyTotalsTitle" class="event-listing-title">Weekly Totals</p>

            {% _.each(weeklyTotalsArray, function(weeklyTotal) {  %}
            <div class="event-item"><span class="event-item-span">${{weeklyTotal}}</span></div>
            {% }); %}
        </div>                    
    </script>
```

JS:

```
var currentMonth = moment().format('YYYY-MM');
var nextMonth = moment().add('month', 1).format('YYYY-MM');
var deposits = {2 : 2514.76, 4 : 685.39, 5 : 1217.43, 10 : 1532.11, 11 : 884.32, 12 : 942.71, 16 : 3099.43, 18 : 433.21, 20 : 731.55, 24 : 2131.68}
var events = [            
];

for (var day in deposits) {
    events.push({ date: currentMonth + '-' + day, title: '' + deposits[day] })            
}
//Just adding this to show day in additional month shows up
events.push({ date: '2015-4-1', title: '5000' })

var calendar = $('#full-clndr').clndr({
    template: $("#clndrTemplate").html(),
    daysOfTheWeek: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
    numberOfRows: 5,
    showAdjacentMonths: true,
    adjacentDaysChangeMonth: false,
    constraints: {
        startDate: moment().subtract(15, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
    },
    events: events

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props to the creator of CLNDR "kylestetz" for answering my question on GitHub:

https://github.com/kylestetz/CLNDR/issues/159#issuecomment-83527323

Turns out I needed to make sure my date formats followed the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard

I changed:

```
    var deposits = {2 : 2514.76, 4 : 685.39, 5 : 1217.43, 10 : 1532.11, 11 : 884.32, 12 : 942.71, 16 : 3099.43, 18 : 433.21, 20 : 731.55, 24 : 2131.68}
```

To:

```
    var deposits = {'02' : 2514.76, '04' : 685.39, '05' : 1217.43, '10' : 1532.11, '11' : 884.32, '12' : 942.71, '16' : 3099.43, '18' : 433.21, '20' : 731.55, '24' : 2131.68}
```

The for each loop now adds the events in the correct date format.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y072a94e/4/